# NHibernate MySQL Password Function

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, passwords

I am trying to create a custom application that allows for adding and removing and changing passwords of users. How would I create the hash that MySQL uses to stored password in?

I know MySQL has a Password() function but I can't figure out how to use this function in NHibernate.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of users are you talking about, mysql users or application users?

If you want to set the password of a mysql user, you don't need to use the password() function at all.

CREATE USER:

```
create user 'scott' identified by 'tiger';
```

UPDATE PASSWORD:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'scott' identified by 'newpassword';
```

If you are talking about application users, don't use the mysql password() function. Use something like sha1(), md5(), etc.

Comment: I need to create users for mysql. How do you change a password? Alter user 'scott' identified by 'tiger'?

Comment: Oh right, the second one JUST updates the password? doesn't give full permissions to *.*?

Comment: Yes, quoting the manual: "You can also use a GRANT USAGE statement at the global level (ON *.*) to assign a password to an account without affecting the account's current privileges"
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/passwords.html